# The Cantor set is homeomorphic to infinite product of $\{0,1\}$ with itself - cylinder basis - and it topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, cantor-set, product-space

I know the Cantor set probably comes up in homework questions all the time but I didn't find many clues - that I understood at least.

I am, for a homework problem, supposed to show that the Cantor set is homeomorphic to the infinite product (I am assuming countably infinite?) of $\{0,1\}$ with itself.

So members of this two-point space(?) are things like $(0,0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1,1,1,1,1)$, etc.

Firstly, I think that a homeomorphism (the 'topological isomorhism') is a mapping between two topologies (for the Cantor sets which topology is this? discrete?) that have continuous, bijective functions.

So I am pretty lost and don't even know what more to say! :( I have seen something like this in reading some texts, something about $$f: \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\,\frac{a_i}{3^i} \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\,\frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} ,$$ for $a_i = 0,2$. But in some ways this seems to be a 'complement' of what I need.... Apparently I am to use ternary numbers represented using only $0$'s and $1$'s in; for example, $0.a_1\,a_2\,\ldots = 0.01011101$?

Thanks much for any help starting out!

---

Here is the verbatim homework question:

> The standard measure on the Cantor set is given by the Cantor $\phi$ function which is constant on missing thirds and dyadic on ternary rationals.
>
> Show the Cantor set is homeomorphic to the infinite product of $\{0,1\}$ with itself.
>
> How should we topologize this product?
>
> (Hint: this product is the same as the set of all infinite binary sequences)
>
> Fix a binary $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ (for e.g., $(0,1,1,0,0,0)$ if $n = 6$).
>
> Show that the Cantor measure of points ($b_k$) with $b_k=a_k$ for $k \leq n$ and $b_k \in \{0,1\}$ arbitrary for $k>n$, is exactly $1/2^n$. These are called cylinders. (They are the open sets, but also closed!)

Comment: For some bibliography: Topology by James Dugundji, chapter IV section 4 has a detailed proof along with an application to Peano Curves.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I’m going to assume that *Cantor set* here refers to the standard middle-thirds Cantor set $C$ described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). It can be described as the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ having ternary expansions using only the digits $0$ and $2$, i.e., real numbers of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n},$$ where each $a_n$ is either $0$ or $2$.

For each positive integer $n$ let $D_n = \{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology, and let $$X = \prod_{n=1}^\infty D_n$$ with the product topology. Elements of $X$ are *infinite* sequences of $0$’s and $1$’s, so $(0,0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1,1,1,1,1)$ are not elements of $X$; if you pad these with an infinite string of $0$’s to get $(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,\dots)$, however, you do get points of $X$. A more interesting point of $X$ is the sequence $(p_n)_n$, where $p_n = 1$ if $n$ is prime, and $p_n = 0$ if $n$ is not prime.

Your problem is to show that $C$, with the topology that it inherits from $\mathbb{R}$, is homeomorphic to $X$. To do that, you must find a bijection $h:C\to D$ such that both $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are continuous. The suggestion that you found is to let $$h\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{3^n}\right) = \left(\frac{a_1}2,\frac{a_2}2,\frac{a_3}2,\dots\right).$$ Note that $$\frac{a_n}2 = \begin{cases}0,&\text{if }a_n=0\\1,&\text{if }a_n=2,\end{cases}$$ so this really does define a point in $X$. This really is a bijection: if $b = (b_n)_n \in X$, $$h^{-1}(b) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2b_n}{3^n}.$$

Comment: @nate: The answer to your first question is *yes*, provided that you look only at series in which all of the $a_n$’2 are $0$ or $2$. When you remove $(1/3,2/3)$, you get rid of all of the numbers whose only ternary expansions begin $0.1$. When you remove $(1/9,2/9)\cup(7/9,8/9)$ you get rid of those whose only ternary expansions begin $0.01$ or $0.21$. And so on. For your second question: no, $D_3 = \{0,1\}$. It’s just one of the factor spaces in the infinite product. A sequence of $0$’s and $1$’s is a member of that product.

Comment: I guess I am getting it, albeit slowly. My main confusion (for another posting when I get it worded well) is from the "cantor set" page on wikipedia where the author says to take the binary representation of $3/5_{10} \mapsto 0.10011001..._{2}$ and replace all the 1's by 2's. In base-3 (with 0,1,2), 3/5 is 0.12101210... I guess this will have to be another posting or look into it some more - this exchange 1's by 2's. Or is this a trick to just get rid of the middle thirds?

Comment: @nate: It’s just a trick to get rid of the middle thirds. When you replace the $1$’s in a binary expansion by $2$’s and interpret the result in ternary, you *will* gave a different number. In fact, the two binary expansions of a dyadic rational will give you different numbers: $1/2_\text{ten}=0.10000\dots_\text{two}$ gives you $0.20000\dots_\text{three}=2/3_\text{ten}$, while $1/2_\text{ten}=0.01111\dots_\text{two}$ gives you $0.02222\dots_\text{three}=1/3_\text{ten}$: you’ve split $1/2_\text{ten}$ in two.

Comment: Fascinating! Well I do recall seeing somewhere (I'll have to read up on it) the possibility for non-injective relations between number systems. Well I fully understand my homework problem and see how/why it is asking for base-3 numbers using 0's and 1's, and not 2's. Thank you much!

Comment: How can we prove that $h$ is continuous? I mean, what is $f^{-1} (B)$ with $B$ a basic open set of $ \{0,1\} ^{\mathbb{N} }$? I don't see it.

Comment: @Whoknows: Let $\sigma=\langle b_0,\ldots,b_n\rangle$ be a finite sequence of zeroes and ones, and let $$B(\sigma)=\{x\in X:x_k=b_k\text{ for }k=0,\ldots,n\}\;;$$ the sets $B(\sigma)$ are a base for $X$. $h^{-1}[B(\sigma)]$ is the set of all points of $C$ whose ternary expansions begin $0.(2b_0)(2b_1)\ldots(2b_n)$, and it’s not hard to check that this is a clopen set in $C$. In fact it’s the set of points in $C$ that are in one of the closed intervals at stage $n+1$ of the [usual construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set).

Comment: Is it only I who wonders what's so interesting about $\sum3^{-p_n}$?

Answer (score 12):

Note that the $1/3$-Cantor set in $[0,1]$ can be represented as the set of real numbers of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/3^n$ where $a_n\in\{0,2\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. A homeomorphism you are looking for is the function $f$ which maps the point $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/3^n$ in the Cantor set to the sequence $(a_n/2)_{n=1}^\infty$ in the product $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. The product $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ consists of countably infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s. Note that no finite tuple such as $(0,0,0,1)$ is in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. The product is topologized so that each factor $\{0,1\}$ is given the discrete topology and then the product is given the [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

You want to prove that $f$ is a continuous and open bijection. The bijectiveness is very easy to show. For the continuity you may want to use the fact that the product topology of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is generated by the sets of the form $U(N,a)=\{(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}:a_N=a\}$ where $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\in\{0,1\}$, and hence it suffices to show that the preimages of these sets $U(N,a)$ are open in the Cantor set. Finally to show that $f$ is open you can use the following general fact: a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is open.

Comment: Thank you too for the effort. I need to read more about how to show $f$ is open. However, I am a little stuck on proving the bijectiveness. I got the injectivity by saying that any two different preimage elements result in different elements in the image set. But how about the surjectivity? That is still hard..... Any advice?

Comment: @nate: If you know that the Cantor set is the same as $\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/3^n:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}(a_n\in\{0,2\})\}$, then the surjectivity is easy to see: pick $y=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, then $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2a_n/3^n$ is in the Cantor set and $f(x)=y$.

Comment: @nate: The proof of the last claim is a nice little interplay between compactness and closedness. First note that a bijection is open iff it is closed (follows easily from 'a subset is open iff the complement is closed'). Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous bijection between a compact and a Hausdorff space. Pick a closed subset $F$ of $X$. Since a closed subset of a compact space is compact and $f$ is continuous, $f(F)$ is compact. Since a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed, $f(F)$ is closed in $Y$. Hence $f$ is a closed (equivalently open) function.

Answer (score 3):

The Cantor set consists of numbers whose ternary expansion uses only $0$s and $2$s. So there's a "natural" bijection between the cantor set and $\{0,1\}^\omega$, or rather $\{0,2\}^\omega$. Everything else should just "work out".

Note that $\{0,1\}^\omega$ consists of all *infinite* sequences of $0$ and $1$.