# Let $X$ be the two point set with the discrete topology. Let $X^\omega$ be the countable infinite cartesian product of $X$ with itself.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be the two point set with the discrete topology. Let $X^\omega$ be the countable infinite Cartesian product of $X$ with itself.
>
> Prove or disprove: the box topology on $X^\omega$ is discrete.

So what I don't get is what a two point set is? I'm guessing it is the set $\{0,1\}$. To prove something is discrete space we have to show that every subset of $X$ is open (and hence closed) but I don't know how to go about doing this?
Please can someone help me with the proof?

The box topology is an infinite product of open sets.

Since the base space is discrete, taking arbitrary products of discrete sets gives discrete sets. An arbitrary element of $X^\omega$ in this topology can be thought of as just ({$x$1},{$x$2},...,) which an infinite product of open sets, and is open in the box topology. This proves that the box topology gives the discrete topology on the infinite product as claimed.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried. Also, please ask one question at a time.

Comment: With the box topology, it is discrete.  With thr product topology it is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Comment: I have no idea how to start this proof. Please can someone tell me how to start it...

Comment: @AnjeliFord Start with the definition of "discrete". How do you prove/disprove that a space is discrete?

Comment: You prove a space is discrete by showing every subset of X is open (and hence closed)...

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69905/the-cantor-set-is-homeomorphic-to-infinite-product-of-0-1-with-itself-cy?rq=1)

Comment: @AlexRavsky but mine is the cartesian product with x itself?

Comment: @AnjeliFord Yes, as I understood, $X^\omega=\{0,1\}^\omega$ endowed with the Tychonoff product topology, that is $X^\omega$ is a Cantor set.

Comment: i have edited the question and need help with the proof if anyone can help @WilliamElliot

Comment: removed becaused of obnoxious time limit

Comment: A two point set is a set with exactly two elements.  Call them a,b.  So every two point set has the form {a,b}.

Answer (score 0):

A base set is {x1} × {x2} × {x3} × ... = { (x1, x2, x3, ...) }.
So all singletons are open making the space discrete.